# Как в webstorme открыть minimap как в sublime-text или visual studio?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide, frontend

[image]

Хочу найти плагин для визуализации `minimap` в `WebStorm` как `visual studio` или `sublime-text`?

Comment: Коль сделали откат редактирования вопроса. Исправьте пожалуйста ошибки сами. Нет такого: "webstorme" и уточните какой у вас был Visual Studio или Visual Studio Code, абсолютно разные программы. Добавьте соответствующую вопросу метку, а не html/css/js - причем они тут вообще?

Comment: не собираюсь менять, вопрос понятный, про визуал студио это уже сравнение, суть не в "IDE", а в плагине.

Comment: Хозяин-барин, ваш вопрос. Но кроме вас есть еще тысячи людей которые ищут ответы и как будет выглядеть этот вопрос при поиске тоже важно, но это конечно вам решать. Исправлять за вами больше не буду. Извините, если чем-то обидел.

Comment: все впорядке, вроде два человека добавили вопрос в избранное, извиняюсь перед теми кто не понял сути вопроса, хотя наверное им этот вопрос и не нужен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из официального confluence:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+for+Users+of+Text+Editors

File -> Settings -> Plugings -> Найти и установить `CodeGlance` плагин.
Restart. Done.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!